# Get overlay without context

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I need a reference to the current `OverlayState` from a service where I don't have access to the current context. I've tried to use the "trick" of getting my `BuildContext` from a navigator key, but while this works for dialogs and navigation, does not seem to be valid for this use case. I've tried following approaches:

```
Overlay.of(navigatorKey.currentContext, rootOverlay: false);
Overlay.of(navigatorKey.currentState!.context, rootOverlay: false);
Overlay.of(navigatorKey.currentState!.overlay!.context, rootOverlay: false);
```

And all of them return null. Same piece of code, called from a widget (`Overlay.of(context)`) returns a valid `OverlayState`. Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: generally you shouldn't access the context from a place that it is not found. this results in code that is hard to edit and read. imagine you show a dialog from the data layer? it should be invoked from the presentation layer only. Your way works but it is not the best way.

Comment: [@Yazeed AlKhalaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11105538/yazeed-alkhalaf) made a good point, maybe use a callback function to get the `OverlayState`?

Comment: well @YazeedAlKhalaf I see your point, but in this case I think makes sense. I need to show the overlay based on the result of remote calls to external services. And those calls should indeed not be done from the presentation layer

Comment: @FelipeMorschel could you elaborate a little bit more? where would you use that callback and when would be called?

Comment: For example, when you press a button you call that service or something like that, there you pass a callback like `onNeedToOverlay` or a better name for your specific code. You could then call this function passing the results of your external service. Then on your actual callback function implementation you would analyze the received data and use your overlay. Something similar to `TextField.onChanged` callback.

Comment: @pitazzo you should have some sort of way to listen to the state in the presentation layer and based on that state you invoke the overlay method. This is easily achievable if you se BLoC or Riverpod, basically any solution that supports sending state over streams.

Comment: Also @FelipeMorschel's approach would be most suitable I believe in the current situation. this way you separated code.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need just `Overlay` can get it right away. So instead of using:

```
Overlay.of(navigatorKey.currentContext, rootOverlay: false);
```

You can use:

```
navigatorKey.currentState!.overlay
```